# How can I model the relationship between two moderators in meta-regression?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am currently running a three-level meta-analysis, due to the fact that I have multiple dependent effect sizes in many studies. I do not know the actual dependencies between effect sizes, however, so when there are dependencies, they are assumed to be $\tau^2_{(3)}$, per [Cheung (2015, Ch. 6)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119993431) and [Konstantopoulos (2011)](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/51903/1/668199628.pdf). I am using the `rma.mv()` function in the `metafor` package to do this and employing a meta-regression approach, such that my effect sizes `es` (in my meta-analysis, Fisher's Z) are predicted by two moderators, `pubyear` and `subtle`. The model looks like this:

```
mod2.1 <- rma.mv(es ~ pubyear + subtle, 
                 random = ~1|studyid/effectid, 
                 V = var, data = meta)
```

My main interest is in `pubyear`. I find that, after adding `subtle` as an additional covariate, the effect of `pubyear` gets smaller.

This leads me to ask the question: Is `subtle` predicted by `pubyear`? I do not know how I would estimate this, so my question is: **How can I model the relationship between two moderators in a meta-regression?**

Right now, my meta-analysis shows that the `es` gets smaller as `pubyear` increases, so now I want to know: Has the subtlety of measures (`subtle`) also increased over time (`pubyear`)? How would I do this?

The intuitive solution would to simply correlate the two with one another. But this does not take into account that one study might report 8 effect sizes, while another study may only report 1. Obviously, the study with 8 effect sizes will have more weight. I plotted this relationship, regardless. You can see that there may be a relationship when doing this weirdly-weighted regression (`lm` line in blue, `loess` line in red):

[image]

Has anyone run into this before or know how to handle it?

Comment: I'll take a look more in-depth later in the week if I can find the time, but in the meantime, Lipsey (2003; https://www.jstor.org/stable/1049948?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and this CV thread here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262326/variance-inflation-factor-for-meta-analyses) might be able to get you started.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I didn't think about searching for VIF.

Comment: Also worth looking at the variance covariance matrix of your coefficients which is sometimes enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understand things correctly, `subtle` is a variable at the effect size level and `pubyear` is a variable at the study level. If you really want to examine if `subtle` is predicted by `pubyear`, then this could be done using a standard multilevel model (with random intercepts). Using the `nlme` package, you can fit this with:

```
res <- lme(subtle ~ pubyear, random = ~ 1 | studyid, data=meta)
summary(res)
```

Of course, this assumes a linear relationship, but more complex relationships can also be modeled (but I wouldn't use that `loess` line as any indication, as that seems like a total overfit in my opinion).

Comment: Yup, you got it. Thanks, I thought about doing this, too, but wasn't sure. I also thought about doing a WLS where the weights for each data point would be $1/k_j$, where $k$ is the number of effect sizes in study $j$. This would control for the problem that some studies report 15 effect sizes, while others report 1, leading an OLS to be biased. But I think I'll fit an `lmer` object, because it doesn't ignore the dependencies between the effect sizes within a study.